# Rename Fields of Model in Serializer and Form - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to change field names. In my model field name start with prefix `timesheet`. And when i am using `api` i have to use that `timesheet` prefix. I want to remove that prefix instead keep `jobs`, `clock_in_date`, `clock_out_date`.... How can i rename field names so that when i am send data from api body should contain names without timesheet prefix

```
class TimesheetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    timesheet_hours = TimesheetHourSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TimesheetEntry
        fields = [
            'id',
            'timesheet_jobs',
            'timesheet_clock_in_date',
            'timesheet_clock_in_time',
            'timesheet_clock_out_date',
            'timesheet_clock_out_time',
            'timesheet_note',
            'timesheet_hours',
        ]
```

Models.py

```
class TimesheetEntry(models.Model):
    timesheet_users = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='timesheet_users')
    timesheet_jobs = models.ForeignKey(Jobs, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='timesheet_jobs', blank=True, null=True)
    timesheet_clock_in_date = models.DateField()
    timesheet_clock_in_time = models.TimeField()
    timesheet_clock_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    timesheet_clock_in_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='timesheet_user_clock_in_by')
    timesheet_clock_out_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    timesheet_clock_out_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: can you add your model code

Comment: here i added please see

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class TimesheetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    timesheet_hours = TimesheetHourSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    jobs = serializers.CharField(source='timesheet_jobs')

    class Meta:
        model = TimesheetEntry
        fields = [
            'id',
            'jobs',
            .......
        ]
```

you can simply use this. This would work for write operations also